# Bottom view is not clickable when i add another view over it dynamically

Tags: android, gridview, android-view

i have a grid view in my app, i am taking images in grid, 
now i am creating and adding a view dynamically on grid view. 
in this new view . i am adding a checkbox in grid.

```
 CheckBox check = new CheckBox(activity);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams checkparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40,40);
view.rlayout.addView(check);
```

now my problem is that , after adding checkbox , my image view is not clickable , is there any idea to manage it.

any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the setFocusable property on upper view.
cheers